# Phoenix BIOS 2-3-4-3 beeps at startup

Tags: linux, bios, boot, phoenix

I looked at this site http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

and it said that it corresponds to **Display non-disposable segments.**

**What does that mean?** I am experiencing frequent computer freezes due to that.
My laptop freezes all of a sudden and then on restart, it gives 2-3-4-3 beeps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem displaying text on the screen.  The most likely cause is with the video card, but since most video cards are built onto the motherboards these days that could point to the motherboard.

Try a spare video card.  If that doesn't resolve the problem for you, then there may be a deeper problem with the motherboard (regardless of the presence of on-board video).

Comment: The laptop has "512MB ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4570". So, you say that the issue is with graphics card, is it?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/phoenixbeep.htm#, it means "Display non-disposable segments".